# Why order of the result varies on using extra brackets in select query

Tags: sql, select

```
SELECT DISTINCT (upper(cd)) FROM Table where end_date > '08-12-2013'
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT upper(cd) FROM Table where end_date > '08-12-2013'
```

The results of both the queries are same but the order varies. Is there any explanation to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it there is no default 'order' of results unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.

This may be dependent on RDBMS but AFAIK is standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks...The result order even varies on executing the same query as order by is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the order differs is because you have not specified an [ORDER BY clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

There is not implied ORDERING unless an ORDER BY is specified.

Comment: Hehe - beaten by a second :-)